# How to avoid fake orders?

Tags: magento-1.8, orders

I'm using magento 1.8.10.

- How to avoid fake orders ?
- Is there any way to verify mobile numbers also or something else to
  avoid fake Orders ?

Comment: Why do you think these are fake orders?

Comment: @Abdul Because customer has given fake email ID and fake mobile number. Customer has done guest checkout.

Comment: Is this for orders using a non-charged payment method (eg bank transfer), or a PCI compliance issue with credit card payments?

Comment: Give this extension a try https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html, it has OTP verification in built functionality to verify the mobile number before order place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually did this last week. So first you need to pick up a service for an SMS notification, after that you will try to do something like integration with Magento. I have integrated with [twilio SMS](https://www.twilio.com/) and I use this [repository](https://github.com/StudioForty9/Twilio) to integrate it with my store.

After all of these steps, we added observer(`sales_order_place_before`) to send the sms. Then I added a controller to call the template after reaching the success page. Finally we add an atribute to the backend order grid to see if the code that been send is right or not, and that what will  be shown in the attribute field in the order grid.

I think this is the best way to see if the customer order fake or not, but at the end of the day it will be always a way to submit a fake order.

Comment: twillo SMS is chargeable ? If yes then how much they are charging

Comment: Yes, they are, and it's 0.02$ per message. And yeah, it's just a provider that's fit with our business.